# What was used to consume api's before webservices?

Tags: api, web-services

Most of the companies that offer public api these days do it through a web service. What was used before web services were popular? For example, if a company wanted to release a c# public api would it have release the dll files implementing a remote database connection? Or did they do something different from my assumption?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: *Most of the companies that offer public api these days do it through a web service* Do you have any reliable evidence for that statement?

Comment: @stijn most of the major companies * Google, eBay, Amazon, Twitter etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways that it could be done. First, don't blindly assume web services are a recent idea. The idea of putting a service for other computers to consume on a web server seems to have been invented multiple times, some quite early in the history of the web.

Other alternatives included defining a  protocol that could be used via a socket (my company did this for a service that one of our clients was considering launching in 1999), or publishing a dll (or, quite frequently, an ocx library) that implemented the api.

One alternative that became common in the world of stock quote provision is to provide an executable program that supplies data via the Windows DDE system. You can still get such systems today (e.g. from ADVFN).

Answer (score 3):

Even today, the overwhelming majority of APIs are *not* webservices. The MS Word API, for example looked pretty much exactly like it does today both before and after webservices became popular.

Comment: this. The OP seems to think an API is per definition something running on a remote server.

Comment: And the POSIX standard is also an API.

Comment: @jorg I was talking in the context of accessing like the company's database. When you are working with eBay api, you are accessing their database. When you are working on ms word it's more to do with adding functionality. My question was sending out the dll with db username and password is not safe. If that's the way companies did it before. I'm sure they did it in a different way. So how did they do it?